# How do you delete a Firebase app inside of a project

Tags: firebase

I renamed my app in Xcode and that resulted in me having to create a new app in Firebase. I want to delete the other app but there doesn't look like there is the option to. There must be a way to do this, so how is it done?

Comment: there is a `delete project` button at settings->general.

Comment: @muratgu I should probably clarify that I am talking about the **app**  not the entire project.

Comment: you are right, it's odd I don't see any remove/delete app in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of posting this question this feature was not available but now it is. Select the app in your project settings, click advanced and click delete app.